# Android Google Map V2 - Find my location error

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-api

I'm trying to retrieve the device's location but I faced several problems:

My LogCat:

```
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Test.projecttest/com.Test.projecttest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2081)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at com.Test.projecttest.MainActivity.setUpMap(MainActivity.java:82)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at com.Test.projecttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
07-21 22:23:34.072: E/AndroidRuntime(11634):    ... 11 more
```

My MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SupportMapFragment fmap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = fmap.getMap();
        setUpMap();
        }


    private void setUpMap() {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        map.setMapType(map.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("I'M HERE"));

    }
}
```

I also tried to use the codes on google.developer.com however its too confusing can't run really understand most of them and got errors when I tried to run them. What should I do to solve this problem? Comments are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` is not blocking. So there is no guarantee that you will get the location immediately. With that said your location object is null.

To prevent that you should use the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)  onLocationChanged() callback to be sure to get a valid location. This callback returns a location as soon as it is available.

Another fact is if your app never had a last location you will not get one. You first have to call requestForLocationUpdates().

Edit: In the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) it is described in detail.

You can use it like this:

requestLocationUpdates (provider, minTimeForUpdates, minDistanceForUpdates, yourLocationListener);

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping I moved my code into onLocationChanged(), however I'm not sure how to use the method locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, null);